# Best way to access a Rails 3 REST-ful web service using a VB.NET consumer?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, rest, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best way to access a Rails 3 REST-ful web service, developed using standard Active Resource techniques including HTTP authentication over SSL, from a VB.NET consumer?

Consumer can be .NET 4.0 if that is necessary.

Are there any .NET libraries yet that can bridge the gap?

I have already come across links like this (http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/dealing-with-rest-web-services/), which use Linq.XML or XML.XPath to parse responses and generate post data for REST-ful web services. I have in fact coded a system similar to the one at that link, except for a different geo-coding provider and using XPath instead of Linq.

I'm looking for something more like Rails Active Resource, rather than hand-coding the XML or JSON encoding/decoding of every single data model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to consume the service from the .NET application?  (Coincidentally enough, the ad for it is just to the right of this box while I'm typing.)

Comment: thank you for that link, I had not seen it yet. I will check that out. Are there any other libraries of this sort you are aware of, or any that are specifically favored by the Rails3 community for easing interactions?

Comment: @Shmidentity: Not that I know of.  I haven't done anything with REST services yet (for some reason I don't like them... I think I had a bad experience with one poorly implemented vendor service that's left a sour taste in my mouth), and my Rails experience has been minimal.  Ideally, however, the fact that the service is in Rails or any other non-.NET environment shouldn't matter to the consuming client.  If it does matter, I'd consider that a fail of the service boundary.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the source code of <a href="http://github.com/johnsheehan/FoSharp">FoSharp</a>, which uses RestSharp to access the Notifo web service, and this appears to be exactly the layer I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: For future readers finding this question: David's answer was what I was looking for. Since I lack sufficient Reputation Points, it would be awesome if someone else could vote up this answer for me.